# Beginner in Python - Rock Paper Scissors game

Tags: python, rock-paper-scissors

Im a beginner in python and just started making little games and projects like this rock paper scissor one. Any advice to write this shorter or any better? I got kicked off of stack overflow for a post similar to this lol.

```
import time
import sys
import random

play_again='yes'
while play_again=='yes' or play_again=='y':
      options=['rock','paper','scissors']
      a=input('\nChoose [Rock - Paper - Scissors]: ')
      print('\nBot is choosing')
      for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(.5)
            sys.stdout.write('.')
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(.5)
      bot=random.choice(options)
      time.sleep(1)
      print('\nThe bot chose: ',bot)
      if a=='paper' and bot=='scissors':
            print('\nThe bot wins')
      if a=='paper' and bot=='rock':
            print('\nYou win!')
      if a=='paper' and bot=='paper':
            print('\nYou and the bot tied!')
      if a=='rock' and bot=='paper':
            print('\nThe bot wins')
      if a=='rock' and bot=='scissors':
            print('\nYou win!')
      if a=='rock' and bot=='rock':
            print('\nYou and the bot tied')
      if a=='scissors' and bot=='paper':
            print('\nYou win!')
      if a=='scissors' and bot=='rock':
            print('\nThe bot wins')
      if a=='scissors' and bot=='scissors':
            print('\nYou and the bot tied')
      time.sleep(2)
      play_again=input('\nPlay again? Type[Yes or No]: ')
      if play_again=='no':
            print('\nThank you for playing!')
            break
```

Answer (score 6):

Operators in python (and any other language) almost always should be surrounded by spaces, e.g. `play_again = 'yes'` instead of `play_again='yes'`. This is done to increase readability of the code. Install a linter to highlight such problems for you (or use an IDE with a built-in one, such as PyCharm).

```
sys.stdout.write('.')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

This can be replaced by

```
print('.', end='')
```

[Read more](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) on built-in functions to use them efficiently.

Don't use repeating strings in code, it's easy to make a typo that will break the logic, and python won't tell you, since it doesn't understand what you write in strings. Use constants instead:

```
ROCK = "rock"
PAPER = "paper"
SCISSORS = "scissors"
...
options = (ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS)
```

Avoid long `if` ladders. If you repeat something multiple times, turn it into a function:

```
def determine_match_result(player_choice, bot_choice):
    if bot_choice == SCISSORS and player_choice == ROCK or
       bot_choice == ROCK and player_choice == PAPER or
       bot_choice == PAPER and player_choice == SCISSORS:
        print("You win!")
    elif player_choice == bot_choice:
        print("You and the bot tied")
    else
        print("The bot wins")
```

Then just call it from your code. You can extract the game rules into a single line by using a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
victory_table = {ROCK: (SCISSORS,), PAPER: (ROCK,), SCISSORS: (PAPER,)}

def determine_match_result(player_choice, bot_choice):
    if bot_choice in victory_table[player_choice]:
        print("You win!")
    elif player_choice == bot_choice:
        print("You and the bot tied")
    else
        print("The bot wins")
```

And the most important advise: use meaningful names. Names should explain the purpose of the object behind them. I don't know what `a` means by looking at this name (should be `player_choice`). I can't tell that `bot` is a string that represents the bot's choice by looking at this name (should be `bot_choice`).

Comment: I found an interesting post on stack overflow for rock paper scissors logic deciding, which does some simple math to find what should be the outcome, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69444226/how-does-this-short-scissors-paper-rock-logic-work while it is closed, the answer is useful

Comment: Appreciate all the help @QuasiStellar, this was all just homework for me I wasn't too worried about spacing and variable names lol but thank you for the tip, much appreciated.

Comment: @Austin0x "I wasn't too worried about spacing and variable names" that's the first thing to be worried about.

Comment: @QuasiStellar well the code actually works and I ended up getting an A, teacher understood all of my material and the spacing and variable names weren't a problem whatsoever, thank you though!

Comment: @Austin0x congrats on the grade. I suppose the course you're going through doesn't require clean code, but it's a very important skill to learn early on if you plan on ever programming outside of school.